# "xpress" content-encoding decoding tool

Tags: http, content-encoding

Is there any binary tool or implementation source code example, which can decode and encode content in "xpress" content-encoding?

The only thing I could find, is the [[MS-XCA]: Xpress Compression Algorithm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh554002.aspx) verbal description.

It is required to understand the content of server responses like the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: xpress
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 13 Sep 2017 10:56:16 GMT
Content-Length: 1003

<!-- Response in xpress encoding -->
```